# How to refresh graphql data on state change

Tags: reactjs, graphql

```
    import { useQuery, gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";


    const Questions = () => {
        const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
        
        const QUESTION_QUERIES = gql`
            query getQuestions(
                $subjectRef: ID
                $gradeRef: ID
                $chapterRef: ID
                $status: String
                ) {
                getQuestions(
                    subjectRef: $subjectRef
                    gradeRef: $gradeRef
                    chapterRef: $chapterRef
                    status: $status
                ) {
                    id
                    question_info
                    question_type
                    answer
                    level
                    published
                    subjectRef
                    gradeRef
                    chapterRef
                    levelRef
                    streamRef
                    curriculumRef
                    options
                    status
                    subject
                    grade
                    chapter
                    stream
                    curriculum
                }
            }
    `;

        const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUESTION_QUERIES);

        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )

    }
```

Here is my react graphql code.
I wants to fetch data when modal change using state if modal status change to true to false or false to
true it will make api call to fetch questions again

Please take a look how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use `useLazyQuery`:

`const [updateFn,{ loading, error, data }]= useLazyQuery(QUESTION_QUERIES);`.

Then create `useEffect` with `modal` as dependency variable, and call `updateFn` inside `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

You want to fetch data after the `modal` state change, So you simply use `useEffect` and put `modal` in the dependency list of the `useEffect` and for `useQuery` there is also a function called `refetch`, the logic would be like this

```
const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(QUESTION_QUERIES);

useEffect(() => {
    // the reason I put if condition here is that this useEffect will
    // also run after the first rendering screen so you need to put a check 
    // to do not run refetch in that condition
    if (data) refetch();
}, [modal]);
```

Comment: I also recommend reading the docs before doing the coding everything is available on internet if you know how to find it.